# Odin froze on TWRP image

Tags: rooting, odin

I started flashing mu Samsung A5 (2017) about 30 minutes ago, and Odin seems frozen at TWRP image. What should I do?

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> TWRP_3.1.1-0_a5y17lte.img
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay based on those log output nand write start did not start. Nothing that is not recoverable. Just simply:

1) disconnect usb

2) reboot the phone

3) restart odin

4) Try again

During the super important stuff the log states: `DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!` if it happens again you might need to try a different odin version.